# Elasticsearch params presence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, elasticsearch

How do I construct the query JSON so that while filtering it checks for the presence of external params.

```
{"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}

}}},
"filter": {
"and": {
   "filters": [
      {
          "term": {
             "locality_name": params[:locality_name] if params[:locality_name].present?
          }

      }
   ]
}
}}:
```

The `if` clause in the JSON is invalid syntax for query DSL.

Comment: Is the parameter stored in the document, or is it set by the client before sending to elasticsearch server?

Comment: params resemble to the external parameters being passed to the server

Comment: If you know whether the params exist before you create the query just don't add the filter if the param does not exist (with an `if(param) { fquery = new filteredQuery(); fquery.query = oldquery; fquery.filter = new termfilter("localityname", params.localityname); }` Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're right. In my implementation,I append the `filter` term to the JSON `if params[:locality_name].present?` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can combine `existFilter` and `termFilter` with `and` filter like this. 
This will retrieve documents for which locality_name field exist and locality_name field value is equal to your specified value.

```
"filter" : {
            "and" : [
                {
                    "exists" : { "field" : "locality_name" }
                },
                {
                    "term" : { "locality_name" : "your_locality_name" }
                }
            ]
        }
```

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/exists-filter/

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/and-filter/

Comment: Thanks,Dhivya.I found out a different way for the problem.I added the hash `locality_name` to the main `query` variable in the ruby file only when `params[:locality_name]` was present. I'll try this too.